# Bundler, when attempting to update or install, will hang forever

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When attempting to run bundle install or bundle update, bundler will perpetually hang, and not complete its function. The only time that it will finish is when I specify a gem to update.

For example:

```
bundle update
```

Will hang forever unless I use it like this:

```
bundle update activerecord
```

Then it will complete as normal.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What environment (OS and Ruby version) are you running on?  Can you get the version of bundle "bundle -v".  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling bundle?  Also what does your Gemfile look like?  You may also want to try running with the --verbose option

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This problem is due to a missing dependency, or worse a dependency-of-a-dependency.  It's common when you don't use rubygems.org as your gemserver (an enterprise environment).

### Common patterns:

- You don't have that gem installed
- You don't have the dependencies of that gem installed
- You don't have that gem installed without its dependencies
- User account that runs a script does not have permissions to install that gem

---

#### Easiest Technique

create a new gemset, and re-bundle.  This fixes the problem many times.

If you can't do that for production reasons, *and* you don't have an app history from which to reflect on when the problem gem was added, then:

---

### Easier Technique

Having learned a bit since writing this answer, I thought I'd pass on [this excellent article](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/9/24/how-does-bundler-bundle) for how to run bundler with verbose debug output

```
export DEBUG_RESOLVER=1
bundle  2> debug_output.txt 1> stdio.txt &
```

This will dump all the debugging (err) output to `debug_output.txt` and the normal screen stuff to `stdio.txt`.

You'll want to dump `1>` as well because every time bundler dumps a line to `2`(stderr) it will put a crlf into `1`.  So Either dump `1` or background the job.  I do both so I can work in the same terminal.

I usually follow it up with:

```
tail stdio.txt
```

to be sure things have started, then:

```
tail -n 10000 -f debug_output.txt
```

To search with `/FAIL]` through the file for failed attempts to install a dependency.  Find a couple of them that are the same and you've generally located your culprit.  The `stderr` works for `bundle install` or `bundle update`.

---

### Debug Your Private Gemserver Technique

I needed to use this process-of-elimination method to determine that my (enterprise) gemserver index had become corrupted

1. comment out all gems
2. run `bundle update` to confirm the empty-set works
3. un-comment one gem and `bundle update`
4. GOTO 3 until you hit the problem
5. research its dependencies

---

#### When you are done

Unset the `ENV` var with

> unset DEBUG_RESOLVER

---

### Solution for permissions

Ensure that the credentials in your `GITHUB_TOKEN` matches your `bundle config --global github.com <your token>`

Comment: fabulous comment, thanks for this. 

`unset` is super useful :)

Answer (score 9):

You can try the `--verbose` flag too to get more output, but it's really archaic and not very helpful. Really the only way to do this from what I can see is:

1. Uncomment one gem at a time until it stops working, then try to figure out what the heck is going.
2. Remove version enforcement one gem at a time (if any) to see if that fixes it.
3. Remove the offending gem if you can (use a different gem) or lock in versions that do work.

For me, after running:

```
sudo bundle update --verbose
```

it kept hanging here:

```
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: tenderlove-frex
Fetching from: http://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=tenderlove-frex
HTTP Success
Query List: []
```

Not at all helpful. I ended up figuring out that the conflict was between two gems. The following would hang forever:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 3'
gem 'airbrake'
```

I removed the rails version:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails'
gem 'airbrake'
```

Then it worked, but I noticed in my Gemfile.lock that it was using Rails 2.3.X. So airbrake seemed to be dependent on Rails 2, but I wanted 3. I couldn't find anywhere that airbrake had this Rails 2.x dependency so not sure why it ended up like that. Why bundler can't output something more meaningful is beyond me.

This worked though:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 3'
gem 'airbrake', '~> 3'
```

I really think there is something wrong with Bundler, but not sure.

Comment: Sounds familiar. I agree that there is a scenario that can (likely) reproducibly occur and be recreated. Whether it is a bug or just poor messaging, I think there is a fix that needs to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Bundler may not be hanging. I just experienced a 7 minute time to bundle a relatively small Gemfile, and that is on the fastest possible SSD Macbook Pro with a 50 Gb download connection.

Comment: Thanks for saying this. Same happened here. :D

Comment: If docker is involved + a overly expensive macbook, it's not uncommon to see that lag.  But in that case you will want to involve mutagen or ask your employer to buy you a $200 chromebook, which will be much faster.

Comment: @don.najd this is a technical answers site; in 2023 there was no reasonable basis to suggest performance of an M1 or M2 processor could underperform compared to the Chromebook's i5 arm line

Answer (score 1):

When deploying onto AWS instances, be sure your security group allows outbound HTTP and/or HTTPS connections - I encountered this problem because I had restricted the security group too much.